# how to calculate the value of a single LQT token for Liquidity Baking?

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, fa1.2, tokens

In looking at the [Granadanet contract storage](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5/storage/), I can see the amount of tzBTC, Tez, and LQT tracked in/by the CPMM.

Here are those values as of writing this:

```
tokenPool 45805
xtzPool 111379958864916
lqtTotal 51959
```

Based on these numbers, is it possible to calculate the amount of Tez and tzBTC that a single LQT token is worth?

I ask because I'm currently adding liquidity and removing liquidity on Granadanet, with no way of really understanding how many LQT I should be receiving, or how many Tez and tzBTC I should be getting back when I remove liquidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `tezAmount` liquidity you deposit `tezAmount * tokenPool / xtzPool` tokens (with division rounding up) and receive `tezAmount * lqtTotal / xtzPool` LQT (with division rounding down). When you remove `lqtAmount` liquidity you get back `lqtAmount * xtzPool / lqtTotal` tez and `lqtAmount * tokenPool / lqtTotal` tokens (with divisions rounding down).

Comment: Thanks again Sophia. So if the CPMM contract has the following storage values: ```tokenPool: 45807, xtzPool: 111396486543871, lqtTotal: 51957```, then If I add 9740 tez I can expect to get the following amount of tzBTC taken: ```9740 * 45807 / 111396329043871 = 0.00000400516 mutzBTC tokens or 4.0516 tzBTC tokens (but 5 will be taken since we round up)``` and I can expect to receive the following amount of LQT: ```9740 * 51957 / 111396486543871 = 0.00000454288 muLQT or 4.54288 LQT (but 4 will be taken since we round down)``` Is my understanding and math correct?

Comment: @Whirlybird not quite. In this case the tez/token exchange rate is so high (probably my fault if you're looking at granadanet) that that amount of tez equals zero tokens and zero liquidity tokens. If you called `addLiquidity` with `minLqtMinted` as 0 the CPMM would just eat your tez.

Comment: Generally the way to think about rounding is that the CPMM is always greedy, e.g. taking the most tokens and giving you the least LQT in return.

Comment: sorry I orignally posted a command in my comment then changed it to just my calculations using the formulas you gave me (thanks again). Could you validate that I'm using your formulas correctly? I'm just trying to triple check my understanding to make sure it's water-tight.

Comment: If the CPMM contract has the following storage values: ```tokenPool: 45807, xtzPool: 111396486543871, lqtTotal: 51957```, then If I add 9740 tez I can expect to get the following amount of tzBTC taken: ```9740 * 45807 / 111396329043871 = 0.00000400516 mutzBTC tokens or 4.0516 tzBTC tokens (but 5 will be taken since we round up)``` and I can expect to receive the following amount of LQT: ```9740 * 51957 / 111396486543871 = 0.00000454288 muLQT or 4.54288 LQT (but 4 will be taken since we round down)```

Comment: @Whirlybird not quite. There's no "muLQT" or "mutzBTC". The tzBTC amount is already in satoshis. In this case you provide zero tzBTC and receive zero LQT. Please note that it's possible for the CPMM to take your tez anyway if you've set minLqtMinted to zero.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this and bearing with all my tedious questions. 