# how does the liquidity baking CPMM round up or down?

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, michelson, contract, liquidity

I'm not sure how to ask this and I may mess up my mathematical terms, if you think I have then please correct me.

When I call [`addLiquidity` on the CPMM](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5/operations/received), I know that I will be sending tez, and that based on how much tez I send, a certain amount of tzBTC will be taken from me and given to the CPMM. I also know that the calculated amount of tzBTC will be rounded up. I know that the CPMM will then give me LQT tokens, and the amount of tokens I receive will be rounded down, as the CPMM is greedy and wants the most value from me while giving me the least LQT possible. [Sophia was kind enough to explain all of this to me.](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/how-to-calculate-the-value-of-a-single-lqt-token-for-liquidity-baking)

I know that the formula for determining how much tzBTC will be taken, and how much LQT I will receive, is as follows:

```
tezAmount = amount of tez to add to CPMM
Amount of tzBTC that will be taken/deposited = tezAmount * tokenPool / xtzPool tzBTC (with division rounding up)
Amount of LQT you will receive = tezAmount * lqtTotal / xtzPool LQT (with division rounding down)
```

What I don't understand is how this rounding works in real life. For example,

```
If the CPMM contract has the following storage values: 
tokenPool: 161159696 
xtzPool: 41578018471 
lqtTotal: 51962
```

Then If I add tezAmount = 12000 xtz (12000000000 mutez)
Amount of tzBTC that will be taken/deposited = 12000000000 * 161159696 / 41578018471 tzBTC (with division rounding up) (46512951.3892 expected)
Amount of LQT you will receive = 12000000000 * 51962 / 41578018471 LQT (with division rounding down) (14996.9628888 expected)

Am I correct in my understanding that, given the contract storage totals stated above, when I send 12000 xtz, I will have 46512951.3892 Satoshi's taken (rounded up to 46512952), and I will receive 14996.9628888 LQT, rounded down to 14996?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this looks correct. All divisions are rounded down except for tokens deposited in `addLiquidity`.

The way to think about it is that the CPMM is always "greedy", i.e. it always takes more and gives you less.